# Undefined offset error (PHP/Regex)

Tags: php, regex

The script below assigns numerical ID's to paragraphs (e.g. [p id="1"]) in articles extracted from my database, except for the last paragraph, which is [p id="last].

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace_callback('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/i', function ($res) {
 global $c;
 return '<p'.$res[2].' id="'.intval($c++).'">';
}, $text);
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
$text = $r;
```

It works, but when I have my error reporting on, I get the following error **Undefined offset: 2**. It isn't critical, but it's kind of a nuisance when I'm testing my pages. Any idea how I can kill it?

Comment: What is `var_dump($res)`? Then you should find your error. That said, don't parse/edit HTML with regex - use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: You made group 2 optional. Which means that if there is `<p>` group 2 won't exist. My suggestion? You don't need group 1 so get rid of it and use `isset()`. Also why in the world are you using `global $c;`? Just pass it by reference `function ($res, &$c) {`

Comment: @HamZa What makes you think parsing it as a reference would help since it's still not part of the anonymous function? [**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/buOI7)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Damn, I meant `function ($res) use(&$c){`

Comment: @HamZa Yeah, using a closure makes way more sense. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I don't understand how to implement any of them. Can someone show me what the revised script should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've improved the regex by:

- Removing a group `/<p( [^>]+)?>/i`
- Changing `( [^>]+)?` to `([^>]*)`. This way you don't have an optional group, but the characters inside this group is optional. Which means you will always have this group.
- Just a preference, I change the delimiters `~<p([^>]*)>~i`

Now let's attack the php code:

```
$text = '<p>test</p> another <p class="test">test</p> and another one <p style="color:red">';
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace_callback('~<p([^>]*)>~i', function($res) use (&$c){
    return '<p'.$res[1].' id="'.$c++.'">';
}, $text);

var_dump($r, $c);
```

Note that I used a closure `use (&$c)` with a reference `&`. This way we can update `$c`.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/142897)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanatory notes. One question, though. Do you know how to modify your script so that the LAST paragraph has the ID "last" instead of a numerical ID?